# Differential equation with integration factor 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

please help me to solve this differential equation by integration factor :

$
(3y-xy+2)dx+xdy=0
$

I tried to solve this and got $x^2 -x$ as integration factor but when I affected that on main equation it still wasn't exact.(meaning I was wrong on calculation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a non-exact differential equation, where it has the form of

\begin{align*} M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0 \tag{1} \end{align*}

where $M(x,y) = 3y - xy +2$ and $N(x,y) = x$. Recall that you want to see if

$\frac{M_y - N_x}{N}$ is a function of $x$ only or $\frac{N_x - M_y}{M}$ is a function of $y$ only.

Calculating $\frac{M_y - N_x}{N}$, we have it equals $\frac{2-x}{x}$. The integrating factor is

\begin{align*} e^{\int \frac{2-x}{x}dx} = x^2e^{-x} \end{align*}

From there you should have

\begin{align*} x^2(e^{-x})(3y-xy+2)dx + x^2(e^{-x})(x)dy = 0 \end{align*}

is exact. Find the general solution to this exact equation and you have your answer.

------ Update -----------------------

Your solution comes out to

\begin{align*} y(e^{-x}x^3) + 2e^{-x}(-2-2x-x^2) = 0 \end{align*}

After multiplying our integrating factor across our non-exact differential equations, we have

\begin{align*} e^{-x}(3x^2y - x^3y + 2x^2)dx + e^{-x}x^3dy = 0 \end{align*}

We have that $\int e^{-x}x^3 dy = e^{-x}x^3y + g(x)$ (Remember that we partially integrated with respect to $y$ so we treated $x$ as a constant, so that you have a function of $g(x)$ that pops out).

If we differentiate this resulting equation with respect to $x$, we have that it becomes

\begin{align*} 3x^2e^{-x}y - e^{-x}x^3y + g^{\prime}(x) \end{align*}

So we have that the exact equation we got implies that

$3x^2e^{-x}y - e^{-x}x^3y + g^{\prime}(x) = e^{-x}(3x^2y - x^3y + 2x^2)$. So we integrate $e^{-x}(2x^2)$ with respect to $x$ and we get $2e^{-x}(-2-2x-x^2)$.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: in my calculations I found $M_{y}=3-x$ and $N_{x}=1$ which resulted me to integration factor of : $x^{2}-x$. can you please explain what is your $M_{y}$ and $N_{x}$

Comment: let me correct that. I quickly glanced it. I apologize and i'll update the answer.

Comment: I double checked the resulting differential equation. It should be exact with that integrating factor $e^{-x}x^2$.

Comment: Thank you, that's right my calculations were wrong

Comment: No worries. I sometimes make errors when i'm not being careful as well.

Comment: I'll update my answer to address your question.

Comment: you should have $y$ as constant and $x$ as variable

Comment: From the exact equation we have, $Mdx + Ndy = 0$, I choose to integrate $N$ with respect to $y$ (while holding $x$ constant) instead of integrating $M$ with respect to $x$ (while holding $y$ constant).